# MSBuildWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath) fails to compile because of processor architecture mismatches

Tags: c#, roslyn

In Visual Studio 2017 I created a Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool project targeting 4.6.2.  I used the templated code as-is except that I specified the .sln file for the workspace.OpenSolutionAsync() call.

The solution I am attempting to compile with this Roslyn method contains both projects where Platform=Any CPU, and projects where Platform=x64.  The solution compiles fine in VS2017 when set to Mixed Platforms.

However, the OpenSolutionAsync() call generates several of these compile errors:

---

*Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\MyProj.csproj' with message: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets: (2110, 5): There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\MyUnmanagedLibrary.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.*

---

Why is it complaining about x86 when the MyUnmanagedLibrary project has been set to build using Platform=x64 in the Configuration Manager?  How do I resolve this?  This code was working fine one day ago and to the best of my knowledge nothing has changed except that I copied code to a different directory on my PC.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this behavior was that some of my projects had an output path of bin\Debug\, and others had an output path of bin\x64\Debug.  However, the build process performed when you call OpenSolutionAsync() appears to assume bin\Debug.  It was finding old x86 versions of DLLs in bin\Debug\ folders instead of looking at the DLLs in bin\64\Debug\ folders.  Once I changed all the projects' output paths to bin\Debug\, the OpenSolutionAsync() process worked fine.